# What are the differences between functions and subroutines in Fortran?

Tags: function, fortran, subroutine

I was under the impression that the main differences between subroutines and functions in Fortran was that functions returned values, while subroutines change some or all of the values passed as arguments. But then I learned that you could modify variables passed in to functions as arguments too. I'm confused, and can't find a good reference for the differences between them.

So, what are the differences between the two constructs, and when and why should one be preferred over the other?

Comment: The biggest difference is that subroutines are invoked via the `CALL` statement and thus cannot be part of an expression.

Answer (score 21):

Whether to use one or another is more or less a matter of programming style. You are allowed to write the arguments of both functions and subroutines as `intent(in)`, `intent(inout)` or `intent(out)`.

My personal style is however to only use the `intent(in)` arguments for functions, which is also a  requirement for `pure` functions. An exception to this rule can be made when en error code `intent(out)` argument is necessary.

There is a subtle trap hidden in functions which return different results for the same input argument value. Consider a hypothetical function returning a random number

```
real function rnd()
end function
```

calling it once

```
x = rnd()
```

is completely OK. Calling it multiple times in a single expression

```
x = (rnd() + rnd()) / 2
```

can result in the function being called only once. Fortran language rules allow such behaviour. Therefore, the standard Fortran procedure for getting random numbers `random_number()` is a subroutine (and because all intrinsic functions are `pure`).

Where ever you cannot use a function, use a subroutine.

Any function can by converted to a subroutine by moving the result variable to a dummy argument with `intent(out)`. The opposite process may be more problematic.