# How to use intent (inout) in a Fortran function

Tags: fortran

I'm fairly new to Fortran, and while going through some documentation it seems like both subroutines and functions can use the 3 types of parameter intent:

- intent (in)
- intent (out)
- intent (inout)

But when trying to implement intent (inout) in a function something similar to the snippet shown below

```
function cell_blocked(row,col,ncb) result (ncb)
integer, intent(in) :: row,col
integer, intent(inout):: ncb

  if (row == col) then
    ncb = ncb + 1
  end if

end function cell_blocked
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Symbol 'cell_blocked' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

ncb is a counter that I would like to pass into the function and update given a condition and return the value.

If I try this with a subroutine I don't get any compiler errors, so I'm confused why the error while using a function

Comment: You have a couple of errors here: you cannot have a result `ncb` the same name if one if the arguments (the other `ncb`). When you remove the `result(ncb)` or give it another name, you must also declare the type of that result.

Comment: Equally, you have a conceptual error about what functions do: you can have an `intent(inout)` argument (but you'll easily get into arguments about that), but you certainly need the function itself to return something explicitly a "result". You don't here (and arguably you should stick to using a subroutine).

Comment: Hi @francescalus thanks for the help, could you elaborate a bit  more, maybe Im not understanding correctly what intent(inout) is for.
As I understand intent(inout) is exactly to have the same variable as argument and as result, so that it preserves the value coming in, but returns a new value. that is why I have the same name for argument and result.
Regarding the second comment, isn't ncb my explicit "result", I have result(ncb) and in the body I assign it a new value to return

Comment: I have added another question which hopefully clarifies what the "result" of a function means. However, to be slightly more specific: imagine a function `f` used like `y=f(x)`. Much like "cos(0)" has a result 1 this `f` has a particular result, independent of whatever changes are made to the argument `x`. Using` result` just means that the function result can be called something other than `f` when defining the function.

Comment: I tried going through the links you added, but I'm still confused, I think its more a conceptual problem I have, rather than the specific compiler error. I understand we can either specify a "result" or just use the funciton name.
In short I'd like my function to take in a counter (ncb) and return the same counter(ncb), which is why I thouth intent(inout) applies. Also I added 'result' and declared the variable type as an integer in the 3rd line of the function so I dont understand why it has no IMPLICIT type

Comment: Maybe my issue is in understanding why  you say my function doesn't have a particular result
My understanding is that it does have a particular result, which is ncb regardles
So it would return ncb if condition is not meet, and if condition is meet it returns ncb + 1

Is this not how Fortran is actually interpreting my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [quite correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27521521/3157076) that each of the three intents (or using no intent) can be specified for any dummy argument of a function, just as they can for a subroutine.

However, the dummy arguments for a function are still quite distinct from the *function result*.  The [`result(ncb)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31061507/3157076) clause here is not saying "the argument ncb is the result of my function". Instead `result(ncb)` says "the result of the function is called ncb instead of cell_blocked".

You cannot give the function result the same name as one of the function's arguments.  (You get an (unhelpful) compiler error saying that `cell_blocked` is not given an implicit type because the result clause is invalid, so the compiler is ignoring it and considering the function result to be called `cell_blocked`. A more helpful error message would include the fact that the result clause is itself invalid.)

The function result is a completely separate thing from any of the dummy arguments, and having a function result is what distinguishes a function from a subroutine. You may (whether it's advisable or not) change a dummy argument (`intent(inout)`, `intent(out)` or no intent) independently of how you specify the result of the function.

Given the function

```
function f(a, b, c, d)
  integer, intent(in) :: a
  integer, intent(out) :: b
  integer, intent(inout) :: c
  integer :: d
  integer :: f  ! Function result unless there's a result clause
  ...
  f = ...
end function f
```

the function result is `f` and the function result is used in the expression in the right-hand side of the assignment

```
y = f(a, b, c, d)
```

The value of the function result is whatever was assigned to `f` by the end of the function's evaluation. Not one of the dummy arguments, however modified, is a "result".

In the function of the question (which is perhaps better left as a subroutine) we are failing to give the function's result a value. If we want the function's value to be either `ncb` or an incremented version of that we don't use an `intent(inout)` dummy to do that:

```
function cell_blocked(row,col,ncb)
integer, intent(in) :: row,col, ncb
integer :: cell_blocked

! One of many ways writing this logic
  if (row == col) then
    cell_blocked = ncb + 1
  else
    cell_blocked = ncb
  end if

end function cell_blocked
```

You may then write something like

```
ncb = cell_blocked(row, col, ncb)
```

but one then wonders whether a subroutine is what was wanted all along.

Comment: This was very helpfull! I think this specificlly I wasnt understanding
"The result(ncb) clause here is not saying "the argument ncb is the result of my function".
But with the further details I see now what you mean thanks a lot!

Comment: In regards to the last remark, in Fortran one doesn't usually write something like this '''ncb = cell_blocked(row, col, ncb)'''? 
Or this cases where one needs to update a value are meant more for subroutines?

Comment: It can make sense to write that, but if you're always going to update that third argument a subroutine would be more natural. A subroutine encodes the intention behind the code, where a function can be used much more generally such as in `ppp=cell_blocked(row, col, ncb)` or `print *, 154+cell_blocked(row, col, ncb)`.